# XML parsing tags with namsespaces using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I was parsing fedburner url 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/xyz' using simple xml parser with following code. But it renders error whenever i try accessing tags :

THe xml structure of feed is as following :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>ABC</title><link>http://www.website.com</link>
<description>mnop</description>
<atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/abc" />
<feedburner:info uri="abc" />
<atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" />
<feedburner:emailServiceId>abc</feedburner:emailServiceId>
<feedburner:feedburnerHostname>https://feedburner.google.com</feedburner:feedburnerHostname>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I wanted to access following tags:

```
<atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/xyz" />
<feedburner:info uri="xyz" />
<feedburner:emailServiceId>abc</feedburner:emailServiceId>
```

Code used :

```
$mypix = simplexml_load_file("http://feeds.feedburner.com/xyz");        
echo $mypix->channel['feedburner:info']['uri'];
```

Niether accessing any of the two atom10 tag worked.

```
echo $mypix->channel['atom10:link']['href'];
```

and nor 'feedburner:emailServiceId' tag :

```
echo $mypix->channel['feedburner:emailServiceId'];
```

How do i really access them?

Since children() function works only when the tag has some subtags inside it. but here everything is in same tag.

Comment: `feedburner:info` is not a tag. It's a namespaced tag, please refer to manual how to work with namspaces.

Comment: @u_mulder i tried method shown at http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302 but that didnt help.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Because something based on that blog post is likely to be closer to the solution than what you've posted here.